# Prove that a sequence is orthogonal in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, orthonormal

Let

- $U,U_1$ be separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert spaces
- $U_0:=Q^{1/2}U$ be equipped with $$\langle u_0,v_0\rangle_{U_0}:=\langle Q^{-1/2}u_0,Q^{-1/2}v_0\rangle_U\;\;\;\text{for }u_0,v_0\in U_0$$ where $$Q^{-1}:=\left(\left.Q\right|_{\ker(Q)^\perp}\right)^{-1}$$
- $Q_1:=\iota\iota^\ast$
- $Q_1^{1/2}U_1$ be in the same way equipped with an inner product as $U_0$
- $(e^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of $U$ and $$e_0^n:=Q^{1/2}e^n\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N$$

> Can we show that $(\iota e_0^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an ortho**gonal** set in $U_1$?

Note that

1. $(e_0^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an ortho**normal** basis of $U_0$
2. $\iota U_0=Q_1^{1/2}U_1$ (in the sense of set equality)
3. $\iota$ is an isometry between $U_0$ and $Q_1^{1/2}U_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Let $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis for $U$ and let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis for $U_1$. Then we can consider the projection $Q: U \to U$ onto the subspace generated by $e_1$ and $e_2$.
Thus we have $U_0 = \{ \lambda e_1 + \mu e_2 \mid \lambda,\mu\in \mathbb{R} \}$ with the normal inner product. since $Q^{-1} = Q|_{U_0}$, which is the identity, so we may say $U_0  \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$.
In particular, we have $(e_n^0)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = (e_1,e_2,0,0,\cdots)$ which is orthogonal. Clearly $\iota 0$ is orthogonal for all $\iota$, thus we are only concered about $\iota e_1$ and $\iota e_2$.

Now, let $\iota:U_0 \to U_1$ be defined as $\iota e_1 = 2 f_1 +2 f_2$ and $\iota e_2 = 2 f_1 + f_2$. Then we have that $(\iota e_1 , \iota e_2)$ is no longer orthogonal.

Comment: Could you please add a subscript indicating the individual spaces to each of your $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle$'s? I'm not 100% sure, if you've noticed that $\iota$ is an isometry between $U_0$ and $Q_1^{1/2}U_1$ where the latter space is **not** equipped with the inner product inherited from $U_1$, but with $$\langle u,v\rangle_{Q_1^{1/2}U_1}:=\langle Q_1^{-1/2}u,Q_1^{-1/2}v\rangle_{U_1}\;\;\;\text{for }u,v\in Q_1^{-1/2}\;.$$

Comment: You`re right, I will see if I can fix it.

Comment: Why is $\iota^\ast\iota=1$?

Comment: Because $\iota$ is an isometry onto a subspace of $U_1$, and thus for all $x,y \in U_0$ we have $\langle \iota^* \iota x , y \rangle = \langle \iota x, \iota y \rangle_Q = \langle x,y \rangle$.

Comment: As I said above, $\iota$ is an isometry between $U_0$ and $Q_1^{1/2}U_1$ where the latter space is **not** equipped with the inner product inherited from $U_1$. So, we do **not** have $$\langle\iota u_0,\iota v_0\rangle_{U_1}=\langle u_0,v_0\rangle_{U_0}\;\;\;\text{for all }u_0,v_0\in U_0\;,$$ but $$\langle Q_1^{-1/2}\iota u_0,Q_1^{-1/2}\iota v_0\rangle_{U_1}\stackrel{\text{def}}=\langle\iota u_0,\iota v_0\rangle_{Q_1^{1/2}U_1}=\langle u_0,v_0\rangle_{U_0}\;\;\;\text{for all }u_0,v_0\in U_0\;.$$

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Comment: I suppose you're right, but since I've hoped that the answer would be positive, I rethought everything and asked a [new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008454/prove-that-a-specific-orthonormal-system-is-even-an-orthonormal-basis).